# I sent login data in postman, but showing error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postman

Ok so I have got this weird error. I am passing user credentials via postman.
In one tab, I am getting an error, but when another tab is used it works.
As far as I have checked everything is same in both tabs of postman.

[This shows the working tab in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojxob.png)
[This shows the failed tab in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1xav.png)

Comment: Can you post the code responsible for handling the `/api/auth/login` end-point?

Comment: Please also show which error message you are getting

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be that the orange dots in the tabs at the top are indicating that you haven't saved your changes.

Answer (score 0):

One of your requests goes to localhost:5000 and one goes to localhost:3000, is that intentional? You are sending the same data to two different services, so it's possible that the response is different.